# how can i scrape data from a url on the network?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests-html

Here i would like to create a program which scrapes data from https://www.futbin.com/21/player/560/aubameyang located at the bottom of the page is the daily and hourly graph sections , the hourly graph is what i want which can be found in the network section of the inspect element which is called https://www.futbin.com/21/playerPrices?player=188567&rids=84074647&_=1608811830598 this gives me a list for all platforms (ps,xbox,pc) of the recent sales history using the LCPrice , LCPrice2 etc... That is what id like to scrape/extract.

Each player are also used by an id in this example for this player the id is  188567 found via the network tab which gives a list of prices , my current code is this :
it doesn't print/give back anything any help would be appreciated

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime

player_ids = {
  'Arturo Vidal': 181872,
  'Pierre-Emerick Aubameyang': 188567,
  'Robert Lewandowski': 188545,
  'Jerome Boateng': 183907,
  'Sergio Ramos': 155862,
  'Antoine Griezmann': 194765,
  'David Alaba': 197445,
  'Paulo Dybala': 211110,
  'Radja Nainggolan': 178518
}

for (name,id) in player_ids.items():
    r = requests.get('https://www.futbin.com/21/playerPrices?player={0}'.format(id))
    data = r.json()

    print(name)
    print("-"*20)
    #Change ps to xbox or pc to get other prices
    for price in data['ps']:
        price = price[1]
        print(price)
```

Comment: You can make use of `Selenium` or `BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question should be improved, but based on my understanding you searching for something like the following example.

**What makes the difference**

Accessing the data for player and console the right way

```
data[str(id)]['prices']['ps'].values()
```

**Example:**

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime

player_ids = {
  'Arturo Vidal': 181872,
  'Pierre-Emerick Aubameyang': 188567,
  'Robert Lewandowski': 188545,
  'Jerome Boateng': 183907,
  'Sergio Ramos': 155862,
  'Antoine Griezmann': 194765,
  'David Alaba': 197445,
  'Paulo Dybala': 211110,
  'Radja Nainggolan': 178518
}

for (name,id) in player_ids.items():
    r = requests.get('https://www.futbin.com/21/playerPrices?player={0}'.format(id))
    data = r.json()

    print(name)
    print("-"*20)

    psPrices = list(data[str(id)]['prices']['ps'].values())
    print(psPrices)
    xboxPrices = list(data[str(id)]['prices']['xbox'].values())
    print(xboxPrices)
```

**Output:**

```
Arturo Vidal
--------------------
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '10 weeks ago', '3,600', '65,000', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '10 weeks ago', '2,100', '37,500', '100']
Pierre-Emerick Aubameyang
--------------------
['59,000', '59,000', '0', '0', '0', '13 mins ago', '12,250', '230,000', '21']
['57,000', '57,500', '58,000', '58,000', '58,000', '14 mins ago', '11,000', '210,000', '23']
Robert Lewandowski
--------------------
['72,500', '72,500', '72,500', '72,500', '72,500', '14 mins ago', '6,000', '110,000', '63']
['73,500', '73,500', '73,500', '73,500', '73,500', '2 mins ago', '7,400', '140,000', '49']
Jerome Boateng
--------------------
['1,400', '1,400', '1,400', '1,400', '1,400', '15 mins ago', '700', '10,000', '7']
['1,300', '1,300', '1,300', '1,300', '1,300', '4 mins ago', '700', '10,000', '6']
Sergio Ramos
--------------------
['50,000', '50,500', '50,500', '50,500', '50,500', '19 mins ago', '8,000', '150,000', '29']
['51,000', '51,000', '51,000', '51,000', '0', '15 mins ago', '7,200', '140,000', '32']
Antoine Griezmann
--------------------
['29,250', '29,250', '29,250', '29,250', '29,250', '35 mins ago', '2,800', '50,000', '56']
['32,750', '32,750', '33,000', '33,000', '33,000', '37 mins ago', '2,900', '55,000', '57']
David Alaba
--------------------
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '14 mins ago', '700', '10,000', '100']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '16 mins ago', '700', '11,000', '100']
Paulo Dybala
--------------------
['36,000', '36,000', '36,000', '36,250', '36,500', '19 mins ago', '3,600', '65,000', '52']
['37,500', '37,500', '37,500', '38,000', '38,000', '1 min ago', '3,100', '55,000', '66']
Radja Nainggolan
--------------------
['2,100', '2,100', '2,100', '2,100', '2,100', '21 mins ago', '700', '10,000', '15']
['1,900', '1,900', '1,900', '1,900', '1,900', '32 mins ago', '700', '10,000', '12']
```